# Using a hash function as a random number generator?

Tags: random, hash

I'm trying to figure out if a cryptographic hash can be used as a random number generator, by simply hashing the random seed and a monotonically incrementing counter together.  I went ahead and implemented this concept, and ran the output through fourmilab's random number test suite.  The results seem fine.  But am I missing any pitfalls?  My implementation looks a little like this:

```
static struct {
  uint64_t seed;
  uint64_t counter;
} random_state;

uint64_t random() {
  random_state.counter += 1;
  return sha256(&random_state, sizeof(random_state));
}

void srandom(uint64_t seed) {
  random_state.seed = seed;
  random_state.counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: I can think of two reasons not to do this: if you don't need a cryptographically secure RNG, this is far slower than popular PRNG algorithms, and if you *do* need a CSPRNG, you should rely on explicitly designed algorithms supplied with the OS or your crypto lib of choice rather than something you cooked up yourself.

Comment: Wikipedia [vaguely cautions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Designs_based_on_cryptographic_primitives) "there has been little study of these algorithms for use in this manner, and at least some authors warn against this use", but cites only one book. Do with that as you please; not being a crypto expert myself, this would be enough for me to not consider it (assuming I needed a CSPRNG, again, if a regular PRNG sufficed, I wouldn't use crypto hashes).

Comment: Well, for crypto purposes the entropy is way too small with only a 64-bit seed. Even though the counter is 64 bits the counter is unlikely to have advanced very far before critical security values are generated.

Comment: What’s the intended use? If it’s for statistical usage, I’d stick with known PRNGs which have been thoroughly vetted. If it’s for crypto purposes, I’d give you the same advice I give my students: Unless you’re a world class expert in number theory and computational numerical methods, don’t even think about trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

You're handicapping the hash function. Even if your hash function has a 64 bit output like [SipHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash), high quality hash functions and indeed tailor made random number generation algorithms often have the capacity to have / have periods (before repetition) that greatly exceed the size of their output. This is of course achieved by having an internal state which is larger than the output. It's unlikely you'll call your random number generator more than 2^64 times, but it's entirely possible, and there's a fix for this that decreases the computational complexity to boot. You don't have to bother creating something like a 128 bit integer class for the counter. Instead, you can just pass the output back in as input each iteration maintaining the hash function's internal state like you're hashing a giant list of numbers.